# Sinon stub check that external SOAP call was called with specific arg

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, sinon, stub

I'm using Jasmine and sinon to test some node.js code. I'm using sinon stubs in this example.

I am trying to stub out a SOAP call to an external service, and I'm wondering if there's any way to ensure that the correct argument is being used in the call.

I have successfully checked if functions are returning the correct arguments in other circumstances, but unfortunately, this scenario is within a nested callback, so I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's my code snippet (I'm trying to test that "client.ExternalService.HttpPort.actualCall" is being called with the "args" variable I am expecting):

```
class ExternalServiceCaller extends BaseService {
    constructor(util) {
        super(util);
        this.util = util;
    }

    callExternalService(body, callback){
        let url = this.util.config.get('blah.my.url');
        let args = {
            'request':{
                'Property1': body.Property1,
                'Property2': body.Property2,
                'Property3': body.Property3,
                'Property4': body.Property4
            }
        };

        //soap.request()
        soap.createClient(url, sslOptions, function(err, client) {
            //client.[wsdlName].[binding name].[operation]
            client.ExternalService
            .HttpPort
            .actualCall(args, function(err, result) {
                if(!err){
                    callback(null, result);
                }
            }, sslOptions);
        });
    }
}
```

As I said above, I'm trying to write a test to make sure that actualCall is using the expected "args" variable (making sure that the incoming body is being formatted correctly to be passed to the external call). I can do this pretty easily for the url by stubbing out soap.createClient and using sinon.assert.calledWith() like below:

```
describe('The function', function(){
let service;
let externalServiceStub;
let externalRequest = helper.myExternalRequestObject;

describe('should use the correct URL',function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        service = new ExternalServiceCaller(tools);
        externalServiceStub = sinon.stub(soap, 'createClient');
    });
    it ('and uses the correct URL when successful', function(){
        let url = tools.config.get('blah.my.url');
        service.callExternalService(myExternalRequestObject, callback => {});
        sinon.assert.calledWith(externalServiceStub, url);
        externalServiceStub.restore();
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to check to see that actualCall is being called with the "args" variable that I'm expecting. I could use a fake object to check it against, but I'm not sure how exactly to do that check in the first place in this scenario.

I looked into soap stub, but there isn't a whole lot of documentation and the example didn't make sense to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)